# Accessing my class from another form

Tags: class

I've initiated a class within my form like so:

```
namespace StartScreen
{
    public partial class SetupScreen : Form
    {
        Battleship myBattleship;
        Control myObject;

        public SetupScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myBattleship = new Battleship();
            //Create Class Object
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access the class object myBattleship in another form, I can pass it through however when I do I can't make it public so it can be accessed everywhere from the new form. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Main Form:

```
  public  class Battleship
{
   //define what you want///
}
 public  myBattleship = new Battleship();
```

in Form you want to use myBattleship:

```
MainForm.myBattleship;
```

Comment: I want to access the already filled myBattleship object in another form, not create a new one.